# Navigation Component issue: errors when opening a dialog using the navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, dialog, android-architecture-navigation

When you open a dialog using the Navigation Component, if you quickly click on the button twice in a row, it throws an

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination ...cannot be found from the current destination Destination
```

Which is logical because it opens already from the dialog, that is, it tries to open itself.

**Solved it with Extension, if anyone needs you can use**

```
fun View.setOnClickListenerWithDelay(listener: (View) -> Unit) {
    this.setOnClickListener {
        it.isEnabled = false
        object : CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                it.isEnabled = true
            }
        }.start()

        listener(it)
    }
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
binding.your_view.setOnClickListenerWithDelay {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.your_action)
}
```

But I would like to say about such a problem, maybe there is a cleaner solution or a solution from Google itself

.
.
.

And what is better to use to open dialogs as usual or navigation components

**P.S.** You can follow the SOLID principle and split the interface and shorten CountDownTimer on SimpleCountDownTimer and the code will look like

```
open class SimpleCountDownTimer(
    millisInFuture: Long, countDownInterval: Long
) : CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {

    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

    }

    override fun onFinish() {

    }
}
```

```
fun View.setOnClickListenerWithDelay(listener: (View) -> Unit) {
    this.setOnClickListener {
        it.isEnabled = false
        object : SimpleCountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
            override fun onFinish() {
                it.isEnabled = true
            }
        }.start()

        listener(it)
    }
}
```

but I think he is not needed here XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from IssueTracker

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177338151

It's not Navigation component error